# Elastic Beanstalk self signed HTTPS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can use Elastic beanstalk with HTTPS, I already created a self-signed certifier and added a listener in the land balancer. [image].

but when I try to enter the URL I get the following error
[image]

Any idea what may be causing this error?

Comment: You don't need self-signed cert if you have ALB. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to use HTTPS instead of HTTP on my requests, or use both not matter, but the things is that HTTPS it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ALB, you should get **free public SSL** certificate from [AWS ACM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html). Then you can [easily associate the certificate](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-acm-certificate-alb-nlb/) with your ALB.

This way you don't need to do anything on your instance(s), including no need for self-signed certificates.

Comment: But I do not use ALB I am using Classic Load balancer, or maybe it's the same, sorry but I get confused in this part.

Comment: @MiguelSato it's same for classic load balancer.